# Usar classe Icon do flutter pelo código

Tags: flutter, icons

Boa noite!

Estou obtendo o código de um ícone flutter conforme documentação abaixo:
https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_for_web/latest/material/Icons-class.html

Sendo assim, conforme documentação para utlizar o icon add box devo utilizar o seguinte código:

```
const IconData(0xe146, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')
```

Sendo assim, apliquei em meu app:

```
Icon(
    IconData(0xe146, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
    size: constraints.maxHeight * .035,
    color: Colors.white,)
```

Porém ao rodar o app o ícone apresentado é outro e não o add_box, conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: icon trocado]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A página que você está consultando,

> https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_for_web/latest/material/Icons-class.html

Se você reparar bem, não é a página oficial da documentação Flutter. Ela começa com `pub.dev` o que indica que é um pacote customizado que deveria ser utilizado como dependência (e incluso em seu arquivo `pubspec.yaml`). O nome desse pacote é [flutter_for_web](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_for_web). Acredito que essa não era a sua intenção, mas mesmo que fosse, ao clicar no canto superior esquerdo da página e ir para a página do pacote, vemos que ele foi descontinuado. Ele teve apenas uma versão desde que foi lançado e nunca mais foi atualizado.

Para a consulta da classe de ícones do material design incluso no Flutter, utilize a [documentação oficial](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html) (do site flutter.dev):

```
Icon(
    IconData(57419, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
    size: constraints.maxHeight * .035,
    color: Colors.white,)
```

**Porém, vale deixar bem claro que** escolher o ícone pelo número diretamente **não** é a maneira mais adequada de utilização, pois em uma versão futura esses valores podem mudar.

Não sei se você teve algum motivo para essa escolha, mas recomendo utilizar o valor da constante diretamente:

```
Icon(
    Icons.add_box,
    size: constraints.maxHeight * .035,
    color: Colors.white,)
```

A própria página da documentação linkada acima deixa isso bem claro, em negrito:

> Do not use codepoints directly, as they are subject to change.

> Não use os pontos de código diretamente, pois estão sujeitos a mudança. (Tradução livre)